# A program for Windows 10 to turn photos and videos into a birthday clip

Tags: video-editor

The requirements:

- Turn 250 images and videos into a video clip
- The process should be as automatic as possible. Drag the resources, select background music. Tadam!
- Should be possible to make some adjustments to the clip (trim videos, change the duration of display etc.)
- When a video is used, the sound should be of the video and not of the background music.

I have been searching the web for such a tool. At the moment, the best thing I found was Windows' "Video Editor" that holds true for the first 3 items in the requirements list. But not for the fourth one: I still can't find a way to mute the background music when a video is played.

- Is this the right tool for that?
- Is there an option to do it with "Video Editor"
- Is there a more recommended program?

Comment: The tool that does the audio ducking is called a compressor. You could do the video with ffmpeg and the sound with sox, but there will be a bit of a learning curve if you're not familiar with command-line aps.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing (Sep 2020), it looks like Video Editor does not provide "audio ducking" for videos with audio. As a workaround, you could use **Custom audio** (button next to **Background music**) and trim the music around video clips. From [this thread on Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/fade-out-video-and-music-in-microsoft-photo-app/3cee28f1-e921-4629-b5f0-c744f5150e6d):

> The Video Editor does not currently have an audio ducking feature as you describe. Here are two potential workarounds:
>
> - Make the background music quieter throughout so your speaking can be heard
> - Use Custom Audio to add the same piece of music several times. You can trim very precisely by selecting a card on the storyboard to move your playhead, and then back in Custom Audio, drag the music trim handle to snap to the playhead location. Once you have the music in segments you can control the volume of each individually.
>
> [image: custom audio trim]

Unfortunately, if you have hundreds of clips, this may be very tedious work.